# Codemirror Functions and extending the script

Tags: javascript, codemirror

So I have the `js-hint` on my file, as well as the `foldFunction`

I don't want it to be an extra key set, I'd rather have it in my options panel to turn them on or off. Which brings to me to the `js-hint` part I want it to run all the time, instead of only when it turns on for one word.

Has anyone who has experience with this had luck on doing this? I already get how I'm going to get the `foldFunction` I believe:

```
extraKeys: { "Ctrl-Q": function (cm) { CollapseFunc(cm, cm.getCursor().line); },"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete" }
```

Turning that to this:

```
var a= document.getElementById('checkmark');
if(a.checked === true){
  CodeMirror.defineOptions...
}
```

I'm not sure how to further this as I'm not positive that defining the Option foldGutter to false will work as its altered after the page has load.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After code mirror is instantiated you can enable or disable foldGutter using the codemirror setOption method. The following codemirror event handler will fire whenever new input is read from the hidden text field. If the checkbox is checked and the autocomplete menu is not already open, the execCommand method will be fired opening the autocomplete menu. This will result in hints as you type. I've added this to my implementation of codemirror and will test it out.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="AutoCompleteEnabled" /> Enable Autocomplete </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="FoldGutterEnabled" /> Enable Code Folding </label>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#FoldGutterEnabled").on("click", function(){
      CM.setOption("foldGutter", this.checked);
    });
    CM.on("inputRead", function(cm){
      // Show the autocomplete menu when input is changed if the Enable Auto Hint checkbox is checked and the autocomplete menu is not already open.
      if($("#AutocompleteEnabled:checked").length==1 && $(".CodeMirror-hints").length==0) CM.execCommand("autocomplete");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Let me know if you were looking for something different.